# how to enter value in the <textarea> field using puppteer whose style is "display: none" in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I have a textarea field in DOM. I want to type value in the textfield using Puppeteer.

```html
<textarea id="sample" name ="gsp" style:"display: none">

</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `page.evaluate()`:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.getElementById("sample").innerText = "your text";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A `textarea` doesn't have a value attribute, unlike an input field. With  JavaScript, you can use either innerHTML , innerText or textContent to write text inside it

```js
document.getElementById("sample").innerText = "your text"
```